# set custom labels for outgoing gmail api messages in python

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to send emails using the Gmail API client for python (which is part of the [Google APIs client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)). I have gone through the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and succeeded in configuring the client so my messages reach their recipients correctly. However, these messages end up in my own email's inbox as well.

Here is the code snippet that generates a message:

```py
def create_message(to, subject, message_text, attachments=None):
    message = MIMEText(message_text) if not attachments else MIMEMultipart()

    # set message metadata
    message['to'] = to
    message['subject'] = subject

    if attachments:
        msg = MIMEText(message_text)
        message.attach(msg)

        for attachment in attachments:
            main_type, sub_type = attachment.content_type.split('/', 1)

            if main_type == 'text':
                msg = MIMEText(await attachment.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
            elif main_type == 'image':
                msg = MIMEImage(await attachment.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
            elif main_type == 'audio':
                msg = MIMEAudio(await attachment.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
            else:
                msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
                msg.set_payload(attachment.read())

            msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachment.filename)

            message.attach(msg)

    return message
```

and this is the code snippet that sends the message (assuming that `service` is a pre-configured instance of the Gmail API)

```py
message = create_message(to, subject, content, attachments)
body = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode('utf8')}

result = (service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body).execute())
print(result)
```

Interestingly, result shows that the message (by default) has the following labels attached to it:

```json
{
...
    "labelIds": [
        "UNREAD",
        "SENT",
        "INBOX"
    ]
...
}
```

`INBOX` label is causing the message to appear on my own inbox. My question is how can I set labels for outgoing messages before sending them ? I have gone through the API documentation but it didn't mention how to set custom labels. The only workaround that I could think of is to re-query my inbox with the `messageId` and remove unnecessary labels.

Comment: You can't set labels on m ail that goes to other users. To do that you would need permission to create labels in the addressee's Google Mail account. Use a mail filter in your own Gmail account to assign custom labels to your own incoming mail.

Comment: By definition an outgoing email should not appear on the sender's inbox. This is a basic functionality which should not require any sort of extra setup to achieve. I am probably missing something somewhere.

Comment: Have you maybe asked Gmail to forward copies of messages that you send to your inbox? I think that's its default when you send from a secondary address.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out @BoarGules ! Although this is not the case for me right now as I'm using the same address in dev environment, but we will be using multiple addresses in production. I have posted the workaround we're using right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a decent workaround for the time being:

Gmail API provides a method [modify](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#modify) that updates the label of a message given its ID. So what I did is extract the `id` from `result` and pass it to `modify` alongside the labels to be removed.

```py
message = create_message(to, subject, content, attachments)
body = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode('utf8')}

result = service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body).execute()
result = (service.users().messages().modify(
            userId='me',
            id=result['id'], # extracts the sent message id
            body={"removeLabelIds": ["INBOX", "UNREAD"]}, # sets which labels to remove
    )).execute()
print(result)
```